awk and sed not working as I expect with neofetch
I'm trying to make neofetch report that the uptime of my computer is 13.7 billion years, for an art project. I used awk to get the uptime from one invocation of the command (since uptime is constantly changing), and then tried using sed to replace the output of neofetch uptime with 13.7 billion years.
This works fine if I do it by myself in the terminal:
[nixos@nixos:~]$ neofetch uptime | sed 's/30 mins/13.7 billion years/'
uptime: 13.7 billion years

But when I try to do it with variables, it doesn't work:
neofetch uptime | sed 's/$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')/13.7 billion years/'
sed: can't read {print: No such file or directory

Edit:
neofetch uptime | sed "s/$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')/13.7 billion years/"
uptime: 14 mins

end Edit
Doing it with a script: (script.sh):
uptime_value=$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')
echo "Found uptime_value:"
echo ${uptime_value}

neofetch uptime | sed "s/${uptime_value}/13.7 billion years/"

Output:
Found uptime_value:
34 mins
uptime: 34 mins

What am I doing wrong?

Command substitutions aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings. Nothing is expanded inside single-quoted strings. Use double-quotes instead. See "Difference between single and double quotes in Bash".

But in the bash script, I use double quotes?

Use ... sed "s/$(neofetch ... (but keep the single-quotes in the awk command, because you don't want the shell to expand $1, $2, etc as parameter references -- you want it to pass them literally to awk so it can expand them into field references.

This should work in theory, I think from your comments:
neofetch uptime | sed "s/$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')/13.7 billion years/"
But this prints nothing for me. or sometimes just the actual uptime (state dependent??).
Also, I still don't understand why the bash script doesn't work, if I'm expanding the variable in the double quotes

Note that neofetch is just a Bash script itself, so you could also just alter its get_uptime() function to your likings.

Good idea, I would still like to get to the bottom of this though

Also seems like I can't modify my neofetch because it's in /nix/store

FWIW, if I run neofetch uptime | sed "s/$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')/13.7 billion years/", I get uptime: 13.7 billion years 59 mins

@jhnc: check and I bet you find your current uptime value has 4 fields like '3 hours, 10 mins' -- in that case awk print $2,$3,$4,$5 gives the correct value to substitute. OP: since your (real) uptime was only 34 mins, print $2,$3,$4,$5 gives 34 mins[SP][SP] where [SP] is an added field separator that wasn't in the neofetch output and thus which sed cannot match and subsitute. (If you wait until at least an hour, I bet it will work.)

From https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Customizing-Info
and scanning the source, manipulating the output is unnecessary. You could just override the uptime function:
echo 'get_uptime(){ uptime="13.7 billion years"; }' >> $HOME/.config/neofetch/config.conf

After that, it should produce that text everywhere. For example, on my machine:
$ neofetch distro shell uptime --uptime_shorthand tiny
distro: Xubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
shell: bash 5.2.21 
uptime: 13.7 billion years 
$


(before attempting to append the override, neofetch needs to have been run at least once by the user so that the config file exists)

The simplest solution by far would seem to be
echo "uptime: 13.7 billion years"

For a more complete solution, you want to accommodate the fact that if you call the command twice, you can get two different results.
Strictly speaking, also, if you want to substitute a string which contains regex metacharacters, you should escape them. But in this case, the example output doesn't contain any regex metacharacters anyhow.
But anyway, extracting the string with Awk so that you can then substitute it with sed is a huge overcomplication; Awk can do everything sed can, and then some, often more legibly and flexibly.
neofetch uptime |
awk '{ t=substr($0, 9)
    sub(t, "13.7 billion years")
    print}'

This fetches the string from character position 9 (anything after "uptime: " with a space after the colon) and substitutes that as a string, not a regex.
If you really, really wanted this in sed, maybe store the result in a variable, then use that.
uptime=$(neofetch uptime)
echo "$uptime" | sed "s/${uptime#uptime: }/13.7 billion years/"

This avoids running uptime twice, and just uses the result from the variable.

the problem with these solutions are that this is part of a bigger thing where I am replacing different parts of the full neofetch output with other strings, and I also want the big splash image so I have to call neofetch or go through recreating that. Uptime is just special because it requires getting the uptime from the command first

uptime_value=$(neofetch uptime | awk '/uptime:/ {print $2, $3, $4, $5}')
echo "Found uptime_value:"
echo ${uptime_value}

neofetch uptime | sed "s/${uptime_value}/13.7 billion years/"

Observe that you are calling neofetch uptime twice, therefore you might encounter situation where its' output does change, e.g. from
uptime: 4 hours, 12 mins

to
uptime: 4 hours, 13 mins

Which would cause this approach to fail even if you would perfectly extract uptime value. You can avoid this by using single awk command to process output, which can be done following way
neofetch uptime | awk '$1=="uptime:"{$0="uptime: 13.7 billion years"}{print}'

gives output
uptime: 13.7 billion years

Explanation: If 1s field is uptime: (note trailing colon) then change whole line ($0) to provided text. Each line (changed or not) is printed.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
